# How to configure php5 on apache2.2?

Tags: php, php5, configuration, apache-2.2

I want to configure PHP5 on apache2.2 server.

I added

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php.php
# configure the path to php.ini
#PHPIniDir "c:/php"
```

these lines on my apache httpd.conf file. But it is not restarting apache server.

What is the problem? Can anybody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not restarting" - does it crash when you try to restart it? If yes, there should be an error in `error.log` telling you more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the space after application/x-httpd-php

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: Hi how can we change htdoc folder out side of apache folder?

Comment: Just change parameter DocumentRoot in VirtualHost directive of your configuration file of site.
  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
application/x-httpd-php.php
```

by

```
application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: May I know how to change htdoc folder from apahce?

Comment: What do you mean "from Apache"? Web interface? Using web-based file manager like PHPfileNavigator or by hosting administration system (webmin, cPanel...).